# What do red items with a line through them mean in redux-devtools?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-devtools

I'm having this issue after calling an action, my data is being erased, somebody knows what means this?

[image]

Comment: You can click the "Raw" tab to see the data. You're looking at the diff, so it means that the data was not there after the action.

Comment: I answered below explaining the diff view of redux-devtools. If you're trying to figure out why the items are being erased you might want to create a question that shows your code and asks why your state isn't updating as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently in the *diff* tab of Redux Devtools. The diff tab shows changes that occurred for the selected action (in this case, the latest action).

You might see the following in a diff

- **Red box** - A value was removed
- **Green box** - A value was added
- **Red box => Green box** - A value was changed from *this* (red) to *that* (green)

In your case you're seeing the **Red box** as those items were removed from the `roles` array.